# Number of moves to solve a flood-it/sock-dye game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

[ Question based on the [sock dye game](http://www.sockdash.com/Sock-Dye) ]

[ **Update:** It appears that this game is better known as "Flood it" and [is NP-hard](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4420). Also, "the number of moves required to flood the whole board is $\Omega(n)$ with high probability." ]

**Question:** How many color changes (= moves) are needed to complete a $n\times n$ game of $c$ colors? That is:

1. What is the expected number of minimum moves needed?
2. What is the maximum number of moves needed?

Is there a strategy that always solves the game with minimum moves?<sup>*</sup>

#### Description of the game

Given an $n\times m$ grid where each node is painted with a random color between $c$ possible colors, we define a cluster ("our" cluster) of neighboring nodes that contains *only* nodes of the same color and must include the upper left node.

[image: Grid of the game]

We can change the color of our cluster at will, thus extending it. The goal is to expand our cluster to all the grid.

<sup>* Where is the proper place to ask this?</sup>

Comment: Also please suggest a better title.

Comment: You've got $c$ colors in the Description but $m$ colors in the Question.  Could be slightly confusing.  Nice question.

Comment: @Matthew: The difference was intentional to draw attention to the fact that I'm asking for a *square* grid not the rectangular, general case of the game. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do neighbouring nodes include diagonally adjacent nodes? Also, the example you drew happens to be staircase-shaped -- do I understand correctly that that's not a requirement and the cluster can extend into the grid in an arbitrarily complex shape?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1430962: "How to optimally solve the flood fill puzzle?"

Comment: @joriki: no, neighbors are only horizontal and vertical. Yes the cluster can be of any shape.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks! That's a better name to search for.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's easy to say something about the case $c=2$. There is no strategy, since all you can do is alternate between the two colors. Since there is a path of length $2n-2$ (counting the edges) between any two points, no game can take more than $2n-2$ moves. It's easy to construct a game that takes $2n-2$ moves; just use a checkerboard coloring.

At the other extreme, it's easy to say something about the case $c=n^2$. If each node is a different color, then you can always extend by one node at each move, and you can never extend by more than one node, so an optimal strategy will take $n^2-1$ moves.

So now we just have to fill in all the cases in between....

Comment: Any hints about the *expected number of moves* for those two cases? (Assuming perfect play and a random grid setting.)

Comment: If $c=n^2$, which I take to mean all $n^2$ colors are used, then with perfect play best case equals average case equals worst case equals $n^2-1$. At each move, you extend by exactly one more node.